Issue with GSAP ScrollTrigger in Angular Project
I've been using GSAP with ScrollTrigger in my Angular project, and it has worked well so far. However, I'm encountering a bug. In one section, the images related to each part of the scroll are supposed to fade in and out. Occasionally, though, the images do not appear at all—they seem to have a width and height of zero for some reason.
project link
the main files are in  src > app > pages directory
The problem arises when i hard reload and quickly scroll down to the animations section. i get to see nothing.
below is the link of a screen recording if you couldn't understand the bug.
demo video
i tried all sorts of things.
